# How to add csrf_token in react components while having Django as backend?

Tags: django, reactjs, csrf

I am working on a project with React-Django stack. There is a form which was earlier entirely built in a react component but Django threw

> csrf_token not present error

For now, I have declared the form tags and the submit button in html and the components of the form in react. Is there a solution in which I can create the whole form in react along with the csrf token ?

Comment: Nothing came up when you googled 'django react csrf token'?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using you react. If you are using react in your templates and making ajax calls it depends if you have set CSRF_USE_SESSIONS to true or false. Basically if it is false you can get it using cookies and if it is true you can set it in the header. If you are using react as a js client I would recommend using JWT and that way JWT works in place of a CSRF token. Examples of CSRF_USE_SESSIONS are located in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/